# Executing a stored procedure in SQL Server?

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[K_FS_GetDynamicdatatoTable] --'2014031711','1/15/2014 12:00:00 AM'
    @orderno varchar(50),
    @date datetime  
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  SELECT 
     FT.feedtype, BG.bagtype, OD1.noofbags, round(MR.rateperkg, 3) AS rateperkg     
  FROM
     K_FS_OrderDetails OD
  INNER JOIN
     K_FS_OrderDetails1 OD1 ON OD.sno = OD1.ID
  INNER JOIN
     K_FS_bagtype BG ON BG.sno = OD1.bagtype
  INNER JOIN 
     K_FS_FeedMrpDetails MR ON MR.feedtype = OD1.feedtype
  INNER JOIN
     k_FPS_FeedType FT ON FT.sno = MR.feedtype AND FT.sno = OD1.feedtype
  WHERE
     OD.orderno = @orderno AND MR.date = @date
END
```

in my procedure,without where condition execution successfully, and if I pass OD.Orderno then not a problem..But if i mention MR.date then No data found...In this what i mistake ?

Here

```
select * from K_FS_FeedMrpDetails where date = '2013-12-16 00:00:000'
```

'date' data also availble in my procedure,but data is not found...please help me?

Comment: In your query, you want to compare **MR.date** with date only ?? I mean what if i ignore the time from **@date** variable in your query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[K_FS_GetDynamicdatatoTable] --'2014031711','1/15/2014 12:00:00 AM'
@orderno varchar(50),
@date datetime  
AS
BEGIN

  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  select FT.feedtype,BG.bagtype,OD1.noofbags,round(MR.rateperkg,3)as rateperkg     
  from K_FS_OrderDetails OD
  Left join K_FS_OrderDetails1 OD1 on OD.sno=OD1.ID
  Left join K_FS_bagtype BG on BG.sno=OD1.bagtype
  Left join K_FS_FeedMrpDetails MR on MR.feedtype=OD1.feedtype
  Left join k_FPS_FeedType FT on FT.sno=MR.feedtype and FT.sno=OD1.feedtype
  where OD.orderno=@orderno and CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),MR.date,110)= CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@date,110)

 END
```

Comment: @SambaSiva I have updated solution. please check now.. and try with left join instead of Inner join

Comment: np...i'll try for your solution

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49284/discussion-between-samba-siva-and-vignesh-kumar)